# How do you insert ASCII art that displays in the Elements tab of the Dev tools window?

Tags: html, reactjs, ascii, markup

I’m trying to display some ASCII art to show inside the Elements tab—NOT console.log—when someone inspects a webage.

I’m using React, so I don’t have access to the final build, which happens on the server. How and where do I insert this ASCII string to show?

Comment: It's just a HTML `<!-- comment -->`, right?

Comment: _"How and where do I insert this ASCII string to show?"_ - in JS you could set it using `innerHTML`, or even the lower-level DOM Node API (which predates the `Element`-based DOM API we use today): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931846/inserting-html-comments-onto-page-using-javascript

Comment: @Dai, No, because comments are stripped at build time.

Comment: Right, that's why I suggested using the DOM API to insert new comments via JS.

Comment: @Dai Oops, didn’t realise you added both these comments, I was just replying to your first comment, ha.

Answer (score 0):

A bit rusty, but like this?

```js
const c = document.createComment( `
   ____     __   ,-----.      ___    _            .-'''-. .---.  .---.     ,-----.      ___    _   .---.      ______             .-------.   .---.        ____    ,---.   .--.,---------.         ,---.    ,---.    ,-----.    .-------.        .-''-.           ________   .---.       ,-----.    .--.      .--.    .-''-.  .-------.       .-'''-.  
   \   \   /  /.'  .-,  '.  .'   |  | |          / _     \|   |  |_ _|   .'  .-,  '.  .'   |  | |  | ,_|     |    _ \`''.         \  _(\`)_ \  | ,_|      .'  __ \`. |    \  |  |\          \        |    \  /    |  .'  .-,  '.  |  _ _   \     .'_ _   \         |        |  | ,_|     .'  .-,  '.  |  |_     |  |  .'_ _   \ |  _ _   \     / _     \ 
    \  _. /  '/ ,-.|  \ _ \ |   .'  | |         (\`' )/\`--'|   |  ( ' )  / ,-.|  \ _ \ |   .'  | |,-./  )     | _ | ) _  \        | (_ o._)|,-./  )     /   '  \  \|  ,  \ |  | \`--.  ,---'        |  ,  \/  ,  | / ,-.|  \ _ \ | ( ' )  |    / ( \` )   '        |   .----',-./  )    / ,-.|  \ _ \ | _( )_   |  | / ( \` )   '| ( ' )  |    (\`' )/\`--' 
     _( )_ .';  \  '_ /  | :.'  '_  | |        (_ o _).   |   '-(_{;}_);  \  '_ /  | :.'  '_  | |\  '_ '\`)   |( ''_'  ) |        |  (_,_) /\  '_ '\`)   |___|  /  ||  |\_ \|  |    |   \           |  |\_   /|  |;  \  '_ /  | :|(_ o _) /   . (_ o _)  |        |  _|____ \  '_ '\`) ;  \  '_ /  | :|(_ o _)  |  |. (_ o _)  ||(_ o _) /   (_ o _).    
 ___(_ o _)' |  _\`,/ \ _/  |'   ( \.-.|         (_,_). '. |      (_,_) |  _\`,/ \ _/  |'   ( \.-.| > (_)  )   | . (_) \`. |        |   '-.-'  > (_)  )      _.-\`   ||  _( )_\  |    :_ _:           |  _( )_/ |  ||  _\`,/ \ _/  || (_,_).' __ |  (_,_)___|        |_( )_   | > (_)  ) |  _\`,/ \ _/  || (_,_) \ |  ||  (_,_)___|| (_,_).' __  (_,_). '.  
|   |(_,_)'  : (  '\_/ \   ;' (\`. _\` /|        .---.  \  :| _ _--.   | : (  '\_/ \   ;' (\`. _\` /|(  .  .-'   |(_    ._) '        |   |     (  .  .-'   .'   _    || (_ o _)  |    (_I_)           | (_ o _) |  |: (  '\_/ \   ;|  |\ \  |  |'  \   .---.        (_ o._)__|(  .  .-' : (  '\_/ \   ;|  |/    \|  |'  \   .---.|  |\ \  |  |.---.  \  : 
|   \`-'  /    \ \`"/  \  ) / | (_ (_) _)        \    \`-'  ||( ' ) |   |  \ \`"/  \  ) / | (_ (_) _) \`-'\`-'|___ |  (_.\.' /         |   |      \`-'\`-'|___ |  _( )_  ||  (_,_)\  |   (_(=)_)          |  (_,_)  |  | \ \`"/  \  ) / |  | \ \`'   / \  \`-'    /        |(_,_)     \`-'\`-'|___\ \`"/  \  ) / |  '  /\  \`  | \  \`-'    /|  | \ \`'   /\    \`-'  | 
 \      /      '. \_/\`\`".'   \ /  . \ /         \       / (_{;}_)|   |   '. \_/\`\`".'   \ /  . \ /  |        \|       .'          /   )       |        \\ (_ o _) /|  |    |  |    (_I_)           |  |      |  |  '. \_/\`\`".'  |  |  \    /   \       /         |   |       |        \'. \_/\`\`".'  |    /  \    |  \       / |  |  \    /  \       /  
  \`-..-'         '-----'      \`\`-'\`-''           \`-...-'  '(_,_) '---'     '-----'      \`\`-'\`-''   \`--------\`'-----'\`            \`---'       \`--------\` '.(_,_).' '--'    '--'    '---'           '--'      '--'    '-----'    ''-'   \`'-'     \`'-..-'          '---'       \`--------\`  '-----'    \`---'    \`---\`   \`'-..-'  ''-'   \`'-'    \`-...-'   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

` );
document.head.insertBefore( c, document.head.firstElementChild );
```

Screenshot:

[image]